# collect all a postgresql schemas in a python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to dynamically show all the schemas that are in a postgresql database in the following format:

```
dbschema = 't1,t2,t3,t4,public'
```

my code looks like the following:

```
dbschema = 't1,t2,t3,t4,public'
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@127.0.0.1:5432/dbexostock9',
                               connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format(dbschema)})


DB = value_classification.to_sql('dashboard_classification', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

I am using SQLalchemy to write in the database. As you can see it would be more convinient to have what is in dbschema to update dynamically but remains in this format.

I can't find a way to achieve this. Anyone has a clue on how to do it?